# dependency issues with app while deploying in tomcat-server

Tags: maven, tomcat, servlets, hadoop, hbase

i am using hbase 0.94.7 and hadoop 1.0.4 and tomcat 7

i wrote a small res-based application which performs crud operations on hbase.
earlier i used to run the app using maven tomcat plugin.
now i am trying to deploy the war in tomcat-server.
since hadoop and hbase jars already contain org.mortbay.jetty jsp-api and servlet-api jars of older verisons,
i am getting Abstract Method Exceptions

here's the exception [log](http://pastebin.com/1YtcVXYp)

so then i made a exclusion of org.mortbay.jetty from both hadoop and hbase dependencies in pom.xml. but it started showing more and more such kind of issues like jasper.

so then i added scope provided to hadoop and hbase dependencies.

now tomcat is unable to find the hadoop and hbase jars.

can someone help me in fixing this dependecy issues.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing,

```
- Right click on project
- go to property,
- type java build path,
- go to third tab of library,
- Removed dependency of lib and maven,
- Clean build your project.
```

might be solve your problem.